# How to construct a new instance of an enum with generic type which implemented by the enum self?

Tags: generics, rust

I'm a new to rust and I am in a spiral situation.
I don't even know how to describe it.

I have an enum `Frame` implementing trait `Framework` which defines a self referencing generic type `T` and an associated type `C`. The code compiles well except the only line in test function `it_works`.

I need to construct a new instance of `Frame` but don't know any way to. Please help. Any advice or just pointing out any inappropriate design will be very appreciated.

[playground here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c0ac610f408b47c2e93f7ddc02625cf9)

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::sync::Arc;

type Error = String;

pub enum Value<T> {
    Boolean(bool),
    String(String),
    Object(Arc<dyn Object<T>>),
    Null,
}

pub type R = Result<(), Error>;

pub type Rv<T> = Result<Arc<Value<T>>, Error>;

pub trait Object<T: Framework> {
    fn name(&self) -> &str;
    fn get(&self, m: &mut T, n: &str) -> Rv<T>;
}

pub trait Framework<T = Self> {
    type C: Clone;
    fn context(&self) -> Option<Self::C>;
    fn process(&mut self, input: Arc<Value<T>>) -> Rv<T>;
}

pub struct FrameBase<T, C: Clone> {
    ctx: Option<C>,
    consts: HashMap<usize, Arc<Value<T>>>,
}

impl<T: Framework, C: Clone> FrameBase<T, C> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            ctx: None,
            consts: HashMap::<usize, Arc<Value<T>>>::new(),
        }
    }
}

pub enum Frame<T: Framework, C: Clone> {
    Overlay(Box<Frame<T, C>>, FrameBase<T, C>),
    Base(FrameBase<T, C>),
}

impl<T: Framework, C: Clone> Frame<T, C> {
    pub fn new_base(ctx: C) -> Self {
        let base = FrameBase::<T, C> {
            ctx: Some(ctx),
            consts: HashMap::<usize, Arc<Value<T>>>::new(),
        };
        Self::Base(base)
    }
}

impl<T: Framework, C: Clone> Framework for Frame<T, C> {
    type C = C;

    fn context(&self) -> Option<Self::C> {
        match self {
            Self::Overlay(_, base) => match &base.ctx {
                Some(x) => Some(x.clone()),
                None => None,
            },
            Self::Base(base) => match &base.ctx {
                Some(x) => Some(x.clone()),
                None => None,
            },
        }
    }
    fn process(&mut self, _input: Arc<Value<Frame<T, C>>>) -> Rv<Frame<T, C>> {
        let null = Value::Null;
        Ok(Arc::new(null))
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    // use std::sync::Arc;
    use super::{Frame, FrameBase, Framework, Value};


    #[test]
    fn it_works() {
        
        // HERE!
        // TODO: How to construct a new instance of Frame?
        let frame = Frame::<, isize>::new_base(0);
        
    }
}
```

---

**Update**: Thanks to reminding from @rodrigo. I checked document([here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/generics.html) and [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/language-features/associated-type-defaults.html)) later and found out that if the feature `associated_type_defaults` was added to crate there is a path to make self referencing work.

```
trait Framework {
    type T = Arc<Self>;
    type C: Clone;
    type S: Storage<Value<Self::T>>;
    fn context(&self) -> Option<Self::C>;
    fn process(&self, store: &mut Self::S, input: Arc<Value<Self::T>>) -> Rv<Self::T>;
}
```

I made some changes to the code: [**Playground**](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6e46c9e4190333de0d78a37cd8215493)
It works.

Comment: You don't have a single complete type implementing `Framework`, so you can't. The only implementation for `Framework` requires some `T: Framework` as generic parameter. You need some starting point to make this work. That said, I've got no idea what you are trying to achieve here, so it may be worthwhile to explain your use case.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Thanks for your comment! I thought the `Frame` implements `Framework`.

Comment: Yes, but `Frame` itself requires `T: Framework`, so it needs another `Framework` to work.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Can that `another Framework` be the `Frame` itself?

Comment: You want a self referential type? This is impossible in Rust, and I'm having hard times imagining how that could work.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Yes that's likely what I am looking for. If that's impossible I guess the only solution will be a re-design of this hierarchy. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: You _can_ have self referential types in Rust such as `struct Foo { f: Box<Foo> }`, but you cannot have that using generics: `struct Bar<T> { ... } Bar<Bar<Bar<...>>>`

Comment: @rodrigo Thanks. Actually I find self referential generic type is even possible. It need to switch to nightly toolchain and turn on the feature `associated_type_defaults`. eg: `trait Framework { type T = Arc<Self>; /* ..... */ }`